# Auxilio na criação de um componente de menu em React

Tags: react

Pode parecer que talvez eu esteja querendo reinventar a roda, com uma série de componentes disponíveis para serem utilizados. Mas eu me lancei o desafio de conseguir construir o meu próprio menu. Apenas para o aprendizado. Talvez este motivo justifique a perca de tempo "reinventando a roda".

Vamos ao problema:

Arquivo de configuração do Menu:

```
export default {
items: [
    {
        name: 'Home 1',
        url: '/',
    },
    {
        name: 'Pré-inspeção',
        url: '/pre-inspecao/',
        children:[
            {
                name: `Planejamento`,
                url: '/planejamento/',
                children:[
                    {
                        name: 'Nova Inspeção',
                        url: '/pre-inspecao/nova',
                    },
                    {
                        name: 'Inspeções',
                        url: '/pre-inspecao/lista',
                    },
                ]
            },
            {
                name: 'Equipe',
                url: '/equipe/',
                children:[
                    {
                        name: 'Inspeções',
                        url: '/equipe/inspecao/lista',
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
]
```

}

Arquivo de manipulação dos itens e montagem do menu (versão de teste)

```
import React from 'react'

import navConfig from '../../Route/navConfig.jsx'

export default function SideBarMenu()
{

    //console.log(navConfig);

    const {items} = navConfig;

    const menu = '';

    var strAux = ''

    function criaMenu(items)
    {

            items.map(function(item, i)
                {
                    strAux += "<ul>"

                    adicionaItemMenu(item);
                    strAux += "</ul>"
                }
            )
        return strAux;

    }

    function adicionaItemMenu(item)
    {
        // console.log('adiciona')
        // console.log(item)
        // console.log('fim - adiciona')
        if(item.children && item.children.length > 0)
        {
            // console.log('---')
            // console.log(item.children)
            strAux += "<li>" + item.name + "</li>"
            item.children.map(function(itemAux,i)
                {
                    strAux += "<li>"
                        criaMenu([itemAux])
                        strAux += "</li>"
                }
            )
            //criaMenu([item])

        }
        else{
            strAux += "<li>" + item.name + "</li>"
        }
    }

    return(
        criaMenu(items)
    )

}
```

essa versão de teste está funcionando. Ela me retorna uma string com todos os **ul**s e **li**s posicionados corretamente. mas eu gostaria que de fato ela me retornasse os elementos html e tal e tal. sendo assim, tentei reescrevê-la para alcançar o objetivo, e é nesta segunda versão que eu estou encontrando dificuldades, não sei se são dificuldades por ser iniciante, por estar tentando um conceito de implementação errado, ou até mesmo pelos dois motivos anteriores kkkkk
Segue o código:

```
import React from 'react'

import navConfig from '../../Route/navConfig.jsx'

export default function SideBarMenu()
{

    //console.log(navConfig);

    const {items} = navConfig;

    const menu = '';

    var strAux = ''

    function criaMenu(items)
    {
        return(
            items.map(function(item, i)
                {
                    <ul>
                    {
                        adicionaItemMenu(item)
                    }
                    </ul>
                }
            )
        )

    }

    function adicionaItemMenu(item)
    {
        // console.log('adiciona')
        // console.log(item)
        // console.log('fim - adiciona')
        if(item.children && item.children.length > 0)
        {
            // console.log('---')
            // console.log(item.children)
            return(
                <div>
                    <li>{item.name}</li>
                    {
                        item.children.map(function(itemAux,i)
                            {
                                <li>
                                    {
                                        criaMenu([itemAux])
                                    }

                                </li>
                            }
                        )
                    }
                </div>
            )            
        }
        else{
            return(
                <li>{item.name}</li>
            )
        }
    }

    return(
        <div>
            {
                criaMenu(items)
            }
        </div>

    )
}
```

Daí estou recebendo essa msg de erro:

```
**Failed to compile

./src/Components/SideBarMenu/index.jsx

  Line 21:  Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  no-unused-expressions

  Line 47:  Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  no-unused-expressions

Search for the keywords to learn more about each error.**
```

Answer (score 0):

Fala Damasio, tudo certo?
Dentro da sua função map estava faltando um **return**.

Segue abaixo um trecho que pode te ajudar. Usei o conceito de arrow function, mas deixei uma resposta comentada como seria usando function tbm.

Espero que te ajude.

```js
function criaMenu(items) {
  // vou usar o conceito de arrow function, mas no seu caso seria assim:
  // return items.map(function(item, i) {
  //   return <ul>{adicionaItemMenu(item)}</ul>;
  // });

  // Com arrow function:

  return items.map((item, index) => (
    <ul key={index}>{adicionaItemMenu(item)}</ul>
  ));
  // IMPORTANTE: usar o index como key não é uma pratica legal.
}

function adicionaItemMenu(item) {
  if (item.children && item.children.length > 0) {
    return (
      <>
        <li>{item.name}</li>
        {item.children.map((itemAux, i) => (
          <li key={i}>{criaMenu([itemAux])}</li>
        ))}
      </>
    );
  } else {
    return <li>{item.name}</li>;
  }
}
```